# Adding property fora particular Column in a particular row in Datagrid C#.net

Tags: c#, compact-framework, datagrid

I have a requirement like , In the datagrid i can have several checkbox columns. I need to display a warning message for a particular check box , and for some row only.

I did  code for  warning message for that particular check box  by setting property for the columns.. Now i m not sure how to apply this for some rows alone. These rows are identifed by some business requirements.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the CellValueChanged event(or any other similar event that fires when a value is changed) , If you can get the ROW(that contains the checkbox) when a checkbox is clicked, then it is easy to check for a particular value in that ROW and display the warning message.